# SQL - Select two years

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having a issues with following sql code:
I want to print out count for both years (2019 and 2020).
Right now im only printing out 2020. Do u have some ideas or can help me with this sql?

```
     SELECT COUNT(u.id) AS total,  m.displayMonth
         FROM (
               SELECT 'Jan' as displayMonth, '01' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Feb' as displayMonth, '02' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Mar' as displayMonth,'03' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Apr' as displayMonth,'04' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'May' as displayMonth,'05' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Jun' as displayMonth,'06' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Jul' as displayMonth,'07' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Aug' as displayMonth,'08' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Sep' as displayMonth,'09' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Okt' as displayMonth,'10' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Nov' as displayMonth,'11' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Dec' as displayMonth,'12' AS MONTH
              ) AS m
    LEFT JOIN wpiy_veosoft_crm_customer u 
    ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' 2020'),'%m %Y')) = MONTH(u.date)
       AND YEAR(u.date) = '2020'
    GROUP BY m.month
```

The following SQL code print out this:

```
total   DisplayMonth
7           Jan
0           Feb
0           Mar
0           Apr
0           May
0           Jun
0           Jul
0           Aug
0           Sep
0           Okt
0           Nov
0           Dec
```

I want to print for both 2020 and 2019. So the following print look like this:

```
2019   2020    DisplayMonth
 5      7           Jan
 2      0           Feb
 1      0           Mar
 0      0           Apr
 0      0           May
 0      0           Jun
 0      0           Jul
 2      0           Aug
 1      0           Sep
 0      0           Okt
 4      0           Nov
 1      0           Dec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
 SELECT m.displayMonth,
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(u.date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as total_2019,
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(u.date) = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as total_2020
 FROM (SELECT 'Jan' as displayMonth, '01' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Feb' as displayMonth, '02' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Mar' as displayMonth, '03' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Apr' as displayMonth, '04' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'May' as displayMonth, '05' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Jun' as displayMonth, '06' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Jul' as displayMonth, '07' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Aug' as displayMonth, '08' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Sep' as displayMonth, '09' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Okt' as displayMonth, '10' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Nov' as displayMonth, '11' AS MONTH UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Dec' as displayMonth, '12' AS MONTH
      ) m LEFT JOIN
      wpiy_veosoft_crm_customer u 
      ON MONTH(u.date) = m.month AND  -- implicit conversion here
         YEAR(u.date) IN (2019, 2020)
GROUP BY m.month, m.displayMonth
ORDER BY m.month;
```

Note changes to the query:

- Uses `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.  There is no reason to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- The date comparisons simply use date parts.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Very good, the problem is when i run that code it says NULL if count = 0.
Jan   Feb     Mar 
 2     NULL    1

Comment: @Victor . . . I replaced the simper boolean logic with a `CASE` expression that eliminates that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code put year in aggregate function and change on condition

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) AS total,  m.displayMonth,year(u.date)
         FROM (
               SELECT 'Jan' as displayMonth, '01' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Feb' as displayMonth, '02' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Mar' as displayMonth,'03' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Apr' as displayMonth,'04' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'May' as displayMonth,'05' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Jun' as displayMonth,'06' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Jul' as displayMonth,'07' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Aug' as displayMonth,'08' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Sep' as displayMonth,'09' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Okt' as displayMonth,'10' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Nov' as displayMonth,'11' AS MONTH
               UNION SELECT 'Dec' as displayMonth,'12' AS MONTH
              ) AS m
    LEFT JOIN wpiy_veosoft_crm_customer u 
    ON  MONTH(u.date) = m.month

       AND YEAR(u.date) in(‘2019’, '2020')
    GROUP BY m.month,year(u.date)
```